# Why is iOS16's NavigationLink disabled?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

I am currently trying to use iOS16's NavigationLink to show detail views for my list items, but for some reason the items seem to be disabled - does anyone know why this is happening?

```swift
NavigationLink(value: example) {
    ListRowView(title: example.title,
                subtitle: example.subtitle)
}
.navigationDestination(for: CollectionItem.self) { example in
    Text(example.title)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to replace the `NavigationView` with the new `NavigationStack`.

Even though the answer is pretty obvious, it will still maybe overlooked more often. So the final code would look like this:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    List {
      // ...
        ForEach(viewModel.examples) { example in
            NavigationLink(value: example) {
                ListRowView(title: example.title,
                            subtitle: example.subtitle)
            }
        }
      // ...
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: CollectionItem.self) { example in
        Text(example.title)
    }
    .navigationTitle(viewModel.title)
}
```

Comment: a common mistake...

Comment: glad you figured it out